# Управление свойством элемента на View (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как я могу управлять св-ми элементов на `View` из других классов (не из code behnid)? Конкретно нужно скрыть или показать элементы (`button`, `Image` и тд

Update:
У меня приложение имеет 1 страницу, поэтому нужно по нажатию на кнопку `A` показать `ListView1`, а `ListView2` скрыть. И наоборот нажимаете кнопку `Б` `ListView1` убираем, а `ListView2` показываем. Аналогично с другими элементами. Все происходит по нажатию кнопок

Изначально показаны только кнопки. Приложение имеет 3 функции:
По первой кнопке отображается  `ListView` со списком фильтров, после применения фильтра нужно скрыть один (оригинальный)`Image` и оставить только фильтрованный, по второй кнопке убираем `ListView` с фильрами и показать тот в котором хранятся эффекты. По третьей кнопке все элементы на `View` скрываются и становятся видимыми `Image` элементы и сразу же запускается `FilePicker` чтобы добавить туда картинки

Comment: Обычно вы делаете не так. У вас есть VM-класс, вы выставляете свойства, которые говорят, что вы хотите, а View привязывается к ним через Binding и включает/отключает нужные визуальные элементы.

Comment: Опишите лучше вашу реальную задачу. Для чего вам нужно убрать кнопку?

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Это уже лучше, но давайте выйдем ещё на уровень выше. **Что** показывается в приложении в первом и во втором случае? Я имею в виду не наличие/отсутствие кнопок, а _смысл_ показанного UI.

Comment: Я правильно понял что нужно сделать?

Comment: Ага, теперь понятно. Я напишу ответ позже, если никто не успеет до этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто нужно сделать `Binding` на свойство `Visibility`.

Я сделал на вьюмодели свойство типа `bool` и `Binding` на него для элемента который нужно скрыть или показать, также на кнопку которая будет этим управлять была повешена команда

Вот мой `ListView`

```
<ListView
 Visibility="{Binding IsListOfFiltersVisible, 
            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
</ListView>
```

В свойство `Visibility` нужно забиндить булевское свойство, а на кнопку вешаете команду и в методе меняете значение свойства на противоположное. Для того чтобы `View` понял что изменился `Visibility` нужно еще добавить класс который наследуется от `IValueConverter` и в зависимости от  `true` или `fasle` возвращает `Visible` или `Collapsed`

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - это использовать Xaml Behaviors и создавать триггеры.
Например, на событие клика по кнопке прятать то, что не нужно и показывать то, что нужно. Выглядит примерно так:

Добавить Nuget-пакет XAML Behaviors (managed).
Прописать юзинги.

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

и описать сами триггеры и ожидаемое поведение

```
<core:EventTriggerBehavior
            EventName="Tapped"
            SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=Button1}">
    <core:ChangePropertyAction
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ListView1}"
                PropertyName="Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
    <core:ChangePropertyAction
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ListView2}"
                PropertyName="Visibility"
                Value="Collapsed" />
</core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего воспользоваться диспетчеризацией по типу VM, которую даёт вам `ContentPresenter`.

У вас при этом получается примерно такой код:

```
<Page ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- это ваша переменная часть -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InnerPart}"/>
        <!-- а это постоянная часть -->
        <Button Command="{Binding AdvanceCommand}"/>
    <StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Теперь, в вашей VM должно быть dependency property `InnerPart` типа `object` (или там `BaseVM`, или что там у вас), и команда `AdvanceCommand`.

В конструкторе VM вы пишете `InnerPart = new FiltersVM()`, а на `Execute` у `AdvanceCommand` подменяете `InnerPart`: `InnerPart = new EffectsVM()`.

Теперь, чтобы организовать отображение `FiltersVM` и `EffectsVM`, нам нужны `DataTemplate`'ы.

Возвращаемся в XAML. Определим шаблон для показа `FiltersVM` как `ListView` со списком фильтров:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FiltersVM}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FilterList}">
       ...
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
```

(`FilterList` должно быть коллекцией в `FiltersVM`). Далее, шаблон для показа `EffectsVM` как `ListView` со списком эффектов:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EffectsVM}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectList}">
       ...
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
```

(`EffectList` должно быть коллекцией в `EffectsVM`). Таким образом можно организовать показ любого количества «подстраниц» на странице.